# EJB "B" look fails from EJB "A", If A is instantiated in Queue using EJB in Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, glassfish, jms, ejb-3.0

Glassfish is throwing exception (Second `EJB` lookup fails) in following case

> Timer Service -> JMS Queue Listener -> First EJB -> Second EJB

however it is working fine if `Queue` is removed.

> Timer Service -> First EJB -> Second EJB

**Note:** All of them are on the same server in same space.

1. `Timer Service` runs ever 30 seconds and send `JMS Message` to Queue
2. **Queue** receives this message successfully, and calls a function of **FirstEjb** instantiated as `@EJB`
3. **FirstEjb**'s method is called successfully, however it tries another function of **SecondEjb** instantiated in it as `@EJB` (Some how this lookup is failing).

**Timer Class**

```
@Stateless
public class MyTimer {
    public static final  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyTimer.class);
    public MyTimer() {

    }

    @Schedule(second="*/30", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    private void scheduledTimeout(final Timer t) {
        logger.warn("********************* MyTimer scheduledTimeout called ********************************");

        MyMessageSender sender = new MyMessageSender();
        sender.sendMessage(" /////////////// Here is my message for you ////////////// ");
    }
}
```

**Message Sender (helper class)**

```
public class MyMessageSender {
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        Context jndiContext = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;

        try {

            jndiContext = new InitialContext();

            factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext
                    .lookup(NewsUpdatesQueueListener.CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            if (session == null) {
                System.out.println("session object is null");
                return;
            }
            Queue queue = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup(NewsUpdatesQueueListener.CONNECTION_QUEUE_JNDI);

            if (queue == null) {
                System.out.println("queue object for NewsUpdateQueue is null ");
                return;
            }
            producer = session.createProducer(queue);

            ObjectMessage msg = session.createObjectMessage();
            msg.setStringProperty("text", message);
            session.createProducer(queue).send(msg);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
                if (session != null) {
                    session.close();
                }

                if (producer != null) {
                    producer.close();
                }

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Queue Listener**

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { 
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = NewsUpdatesQueueListener.CONNECTION_QUEUE_NAME)
                }, 
        mappedName = NewsUpdatesQueueListener.CONNECTION_QUEUE_JNDI)

public class NewsUpdatesQueueListener implements MessageListener {
    public static final  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NewsUpdatesQueueListener.class);
    public static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/NewsConnectionFactory";
    public static final String CONNECTION_QUEUE_NAME = "NewsQueue";
    public static final String CONNECTION_QUEUE_JNDI = "jms/"+CONNECTION_QUEUE_NAME;

    @EJB 
    FirstEjbRemote first;

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) message;
            try {
                logger.warn("Message recived in Queue listener: "+ msg.getStringProperty("text"));
                if (first != null) 
                    first.hello();
                else 
                    logger.warn("@EJB first is null");

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**First EJb**

```
@Stateless(name="FirstEjb", mappedName="ejb/FirstEjb")
@Local(FirstEjbLocal.class)
@Remote(FirstEjbRemote.class)
public class FirstEjb implements FirstEjbRemote, FirstEjbLocal {
    public static final  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FirstEjb.class);
    @EJB
    SecondEjbRemote second;


    @Override
    public void hello() {
        logger.warn("********************* Hello function called in first EJB *********");
        if (second != null) 
                second.sayHello();
    }
 }
```

**Second EJB**

```
@Stateless(name="SecondEjb", mappedName = "ejb/SecondEjb")
@Local(SecondEjbLocal.class)
@Remote(SecondEjbRemote.class)
public class SecondEjb implements SecondEjbRemote, SecondEjbLocal {

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("********************* Hello function called in second EJB *********");

    }
}
```

**Log of deployment**

```
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB SecondEjb: [java:global/AppleNew/SecondEjb!com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote, java:global/AppleNew/SecondEjb!com.bbc.news.SecondEjbLocal]|#]
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB SecondEjb: [ejb/SecondEjb, ejb/SecondEjb#com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote]|#]
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB MyTimer: [java:global/AppleNew/MyTimer!com.bbc.news.MyTimer, java:global/AppleNew/MyTimer]|#]
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB FirstEjb: [java:global/AppleNew/FirstEjb!com.bbc.news.FirstEjbLocal, java:global/AppleNew/FirstEjb!com.bbc.news.FirstEjbRemote]|#]
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB FirstEjb: [ejb/FirstEjb#com.bbc.news.FirstEjbRemote, ejb/FirstEjb]|#]
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.jms.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMS013: end point determine destionation name, Res name: javax.jms.Queue, JNDI name: NewsUpdatesQueueListener descriptor name : {3}|#]
    |INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|AppleNew was successfully deployed in 332 milliseconds.|#]
```

**Please note** it works fine if JMS queue is removed and timer service directly calls first ejb and than first ejb calls second ejb.

**Part of Exception** (from mid of the long exception, I will paste full exception if needed)

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.bbc.news.FirstEjb/second,Remote 3.x interface =com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote resolved to intra-app EJB SecondEjb in module AppleNew,ejb-link=SecondEjb,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=ejb/SecondEjb,refType=Session into class com.bbc.news.FirstEjb: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.bbc.news.FirstEjb/second' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1694)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:494)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.bbc.news.FirstEjb/second' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.bbc.news.FirstEjb/second,Remote 3.x interface =com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote resolved to intra-app EJB SecondEjb in module AppleNew,ejb-link=SecondEjb,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=ejb/SecondEjb,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'ejb/SecondEjb#com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ejb/SecondEjb#com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]]]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.bbc.news.FirstEjb/second,Remote 3.x interface =com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote resolved to intra-app EJB SecondEjb in module AppleNew,ejb-link=SecondEjb,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=ejb/SecondEjb,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'ejb/SecondEjb#com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ejb/SecondEjb#com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]]]
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:191)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:169)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ejb/SecondEjb#com.bbc.news.SecondEjbRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:186)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:542)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:71)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
        org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:147)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl_with_systemclassloader(ORB.java:308)
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:293)
        at org.omg.CosTransactions.PropagationContextHelper.type(PropagationContextHelper.java:40)
        at org.omg.CosTransactions.PropagationContextHelper.insert(PropagationContextHelper.java:18)
        at com.sun.jts.pi.InterceptorImpl.send_request(InterceptorImpl.java:346)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.InterceptorInvoker.invokeClientInterceptorStartingPoint(InterceptorInvoker.java:290)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.invokeClientPIStartingPoint(PIHandlerImpl.java:376)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:304)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:228)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:393)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
        at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.setOrbAndRootContext(CNCtx.java:383)
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.initOrbAndRootContext(CNCtx.java:274)
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.<init>(CNCtx.java:105)
        at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory.getInitialContext(CNCtxFactory.java:49)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:240)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.IIOPObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(IIOPObjectFactory.java:73)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:138)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl_with_systemclassloader(ORB.java:305)
        ... 94 more
```

**Version details** Its a production server where this code does not work

```
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)    
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
**java** version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

**2 Test environments where it work fine**

```
window 7
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23)
java version "1.6.0_32"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.7-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Test Virtual Machine**

```
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (build 22)
java version "1.6.0_30"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.3)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Which Java version and which Glassfish version are you using?

Comment: Please have a look updated question I have added the details about versions.

Comment: Check this issue report https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047, maybe the workaround described there will work for you.

Comment: Can you please explain this
Specifying the default ORB singleton shipped by the JDK (int the domain.xml jvmopts):

-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton

"solved" the problem for me.

Comment: You have to edit domain.xml find an element with the name jvmopts, and add there mentioned string. This will set the mentioned system property

Comment: It worked for me, but this jvm option is not configured in other 2 environments(where it works fine) as I have mentioned above. (`strange` or `science`).

I have absolutely no idea what I have done. Can you please explain to me what I just did. It would be a great help, Please add an answer so that I accept that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems the problem you're facing is related to the issue [GLASSFISH-21047](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047).

The workaround proposed there is to edit `domain.xml` and add there

```
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBSingleton
```

to the `jvmopts`. Seems like by default the `org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass` property points to the wrong class, which doesn't exist.

If it's up to your statement that on the other environments it works, I think the problem may be related to Java version, as described in the original bug report. Seems like the problem is also related to the OpenJDK.

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks! Just to mention that in `domain.xml` there may be more than one section of `<jvm-options>` to edit. I have added in two places.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, have you tried with calling second EJB with Local Interface as

```
@EJB
SecondEjbLocal second;
@Override
public void hello() {
    logger.warn("********************* Hello function called in first EJB *********");
    if (second != null) 
            second.sayHello();
}
```